# Stable links to latest Boost documentation?

Tags: support, link-rot

Boost C++ library documentation links typically look like these:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html

and I (and others) occasionally [use them in answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48925033/1593077) on the site. But as Boost versions increase, the packages and the documentation get updated. Thus, links with a specific library version become outdate. Is there some way to link to the latest-release-version of a Boost package's documentation?

Comment: What other sites does this happen to, to justify posting this here instead of MSO?

Comment: @Tom There are several sites affected, beyond Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tom E.g. SE Software Engineering, SE Code Review, etc. Any site related to coding C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I might need to ask the question more precisely: on which site is it useful to not discuss code and link to an up-to-date documentation? SE might be a case, but SR isn't. In SR we review the pieces of code with a specific library version, so posting a link to a documentation that over time will not document the used code/library anymore is just confusing. SO has the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can link to the docs for the latest release of a specific boost library with a link constructed like this:

```
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/<libname>.html
```

This is the same link as it appears on the top bar if you request an outdated version of the documentation:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now put that to [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48925033/1593077)

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Glad to help. That was a fairly easy one ;-)